# UITableView Cannot be Scrolled all the way to the bottom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am just curious. I make a few UITableView. In all cases, if I scroll all the way to the bottom it bounce up again.

So lower portion of the table cannot be accessed. How should I fix this?

I mean exactly that I asked. One of the solution is that the table size is not right.

And that is exactly the problem. I have to simulate the size for the toolbar below.

Thank you for those who answer. No thanks for those who close this good question.

Comment: And that is exactly the problem. I have to simulate the size for the toolbar below.

Thank you for those who answer. No thanks for those who close this good question. I get my answer but I think this question deserve reopen. I am satisfied with the answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems your tableView's **frame height** is exceeding the visible area. **Decrease** the tableView's frame height to be inside the visible area. You will see everything.

Comment: Or you can use constraints to adjust it in IB by using 'add missing constraints'

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(widthYouWant, heightYouWant);
```