# Can't scroll UITableView to bottom

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios6, scroll

**EDIT**
This is what happens, so you can see: http://youtu.be/v1HrxYhzJZY.

This is my scenario:
I have a `UITableView` with 5 sections and 12 cells. This view is opened with a `push segue` and everything works fine, it scrolls, etc.

Three of those cells open a `MKMapView` view (through a `push segue`) another pops up a `MFMailComposeViewController`.

When I try to *go back* to my `UITableView` I'm no longer able to scroll to the bottom. I can only scroll *a bit* and then it returns to the top of my tableview.

I tried to set the frame size on `viewWillAppear`, I tried to reload the `tableView` but it doesn't work!
What could cause this issue?

**EDIT**
My implementation are:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    loaded = NO;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"my_url", self.userID]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        loaded = YES;

        self.user = JSON;
        [self setUserValues];

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:nil];

    [operation start];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.tableView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 420)];
}
```

Comment: It'd probably be useful to provide the following information: 1) You mentioned that you can't scroll to the bottom, can you scroll at all? Are you able to scroll most of the way except for a section at the bottom of the table view. 2) Your `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` method implementations in table view's view controller.

Comment: Why are you setting the content size?

Comment: That part of code is a test only! I was trying to figure out how could I solve that issue!

Comment: I don't know if the contentSize of the scroll view would change, but you might try logging it in the viewDidAppear method, and see if it's different at first launch vs when you come back from one of the other controllers.

Comment: Why close as _not a real question_, here there's a problem, instead of closing questions try to help. However, I've updated my question with a video that shows the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved that issue by myself with this simple code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5):

The `viewWillAppear:` method is too early to scroll the table view.  The view hasn't been added to the on-screen view hierarchy and laid out yet.  Try doing it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to scroll your tableView to desired section/row:

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:desiredRow inSection:desiredSection] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

To scroll the tableView, which inherits from `UIScrollView`, you need to use `[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,100) animated:YES];` and not the `setContentSize`

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this too. Coming back from the child view, the table view was no longer scrollable (it would always bounce to the top). My child view doesn't have a map view like yours.

Reloading the table view didn't fix it for me.

The bug only showed in iOS 7, not 6.1.

I was accessing `topLayoutGuide` ... removing that access (just a property read!) fixed the issue. WTF! Must be a magic property.

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem yesterday! And I have fixed it just now!

I dragged a UITableView to the UIViewController and simply chose `add missing contraints`. When I ran the app, the UITableView could not scroll to bottom.

I googled it and saw [a similar question in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408645/uitableview-cannot-be-scrolled-all-the-way-to-the-bottom).

Then I checked the contraints for the UITableView, I found there was a contraint setted the fixed height for the UITableView. Then I removed the contraint and added another one: `Bottom Space to: Bottom Layout Guide = 0`.

The solution works for me.